# Case insensitive String split() method

Tags: java, string, split

When I perform

```
String test="23x34 ";
String[] array=test.split("x"); //splitting using simple letter
```

I got two items in array as 23 and 34

but when I did

```
String test="23x34 ";
String[] array=test.split("X"); //splitting using capitalletter
```

I got one item in array 23x34

So is there any way I can use the split method as case insensitive or whether there is any other method that can help?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use regex pattern `[xX]` in `split`

```
String x = "24X45";
String[] res = x.split("[xX]");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(res));
```

Answer (score 58):

`split` uses, as the documentation suggests, a regexp. a regexp for your example would be :

```
"[xX]"
```

Also, the `(?i)` flag toggles case insensitivty. Therefore, the following is also correct :

```
"(?i)x"
```

In this case, `x` can be any litteral properly escaped.

Comment: +1 for `(?i)`, it can be used for sentences. Ex: `String[] array = "24xXx45".split("(?i)XXX"); // [24, 45]`

Comment: If you have unicode chars you should rather use (?iu) flag instead.

Comment: @ChanTzish this question is about Java

Comment: Wonderful! Mention of `(?i)` was really a gem. Handles all the case sensitive scenarios. This should be the accepted answer as a wholly satisfying solution though.

Answer (score 14):

You can also use an embedded flag in your regex:

```
String[] array = test.split("(?i)x"); // splits case insensitive
```

Answer (score 6):

I personally prefer using

```
String modified = Pattern.compile("x", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(stringContents).replaceAll(splitterValue);
String[] parts = modified.split(splitterValue);
```

In this way you can ensure any regex will work, as long as you have a unique splitter value

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the existing answers, you can use `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE` flag to convert your regex pattern into a case-insensitive pattern which you can directly use to split your string e.g.

```
String[] arr = Pattern.compile("x", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).split("23x34 ");
```

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("x", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pattern.split("23x34 ")));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pattern.split("23X34 ")));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[23, 34 ]
[23, 34 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Java's String class' split method also accepts regex.

To keep things short, this should help you: http://www.coderanch.com/t/480781/java/java/String-split

Comment: @WChargin So true. And I realized it just yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

For JavaScript:

```js
var test="23x34 ";
var array = test.split(\x\i);
```

Comment: okay this is annoying: This question shows at the top of a Google search for "case insensitive split java script", yet this answer is the only mention of JavaScript (so it took me a while to realize that the question -- and the other answers -- are all specific to *Java*) but on top of that, this answer is *incorrect* and doesn't work in JavaScript anyway (error="invalid escape sequence").....    Flagging this answer for deletion since it's irrelevant to the question AND incorrect anyway AND therefore is a waste of people's time.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit complex, but here's how it could be implemented:

1. Lowercase both the strings (overall text and search term)
2. Run the `text.split(searchTerm)`
3. This gives you an array of strings that are NOT search terms
4. By walking through this array, you're getting lengths of each of these strings
5. Between each of those strings, there must be a search term (with known length)
6. By figuring out indexes, you can now .slice() the pieces from the original string

Answer (score -1):

You could use a regex as an argument to `split`, like this:

```
"32x23".split("[xX]");
```

Or you could use a `StringTokenizer` that lets you set its set of delimiters, like this:

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("32x23","xX");
//                                          ^^    ^^
//                                       string delimiter
```

This has the advantage that if you want to build the list of delimiters programatically, for example for each lowercase letter in the delimiter list add its uppercase corespondent, you can do this and then pass the result to the `StringTokenizer`.