# Split string in android

Tags: android, string

I'm trying to split a string. For example "Castle"

```
String text = "Castle";
            String[] word = text.split("c");
            Log.d(Constants.RESULT, "1:" + word[word.length-1]);
```

I expect the result to be (1:astle). Instead i get (1:Castle)
I hope you guys cal help me out. Thanks!

Comment: Because "c" != "C".

Comment: If you want case-insensitivity split you can refer this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581977/case-insensitive-string-split-method).

Comment: I just set "Castle" as an example. it does not has to be that word  or a capital letter always

Comment: Doesn't it mean case-insensitive split?

Answer (score 2):

Use `String[] word = text.split("C");`

Answer (score 0):

Simple thing is that the Alphabet 'c' is not same as 'C',You are using 'c',better use 'C',

Try this

```
String text = "Castle";
            String[] word = text.split("C");
            Log.d(Constants.RESULT, "1:" + word[word.length-1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
String text = "Castle";
String[] word = text.split("C");
Log.d(Constants.RESULT, "1:" + word[1]);
```

you got "astle" from this

Answer (score -2):

Use

```
    String text = "Castle"; 
    String sub =text.substring(1,text.length); 

    Log.d( "Answer", "1:" + sub);
```