# How to split the String without case-sensitive in java?

Tags: java, string, replace

How to split the String without case-sensitive in java?

```
String sql = SELECT * FROM employee OFFSET 0 LIMIT 25;
String[] sqlWithoutPagination = sql.split("offset");
```

`OFFSET` can be in `lower-case/upper-case`.

Comment: `x.toLowerCase().split("y")`?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16582115/3890632) with the `(?i)` flag on the regular expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using regex would be like below

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM employee OFFset 0 LIMIT 25";
System.out.println(sql.split("(?i)offset")[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use a RegEx, you can simply use `indexOf` and `toLowerCase`:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM employee OFFSET 0 LIMIT 25";
int idx = sql.toLowerCase().indexOf("offset");
String sqlWithoutPagination = sql.substring(0, idx);
```

Of course, you would have to check if `idx` is greater equals 0.

Answer (score 1):

I would actually suggest using `String#replaceAll` here in case insensitive mode, to just strip off the `OFFSET` and `LIMIT` clauses, should they occur:

```
String sql1 = "SELECT * FROM employee OFFSET 0 LIMIT 25";
String sql1New = sql1.replaceAll("(?i)(?:\\s+OFFSET \\d+)?\\s+LIMIT \\d+$", "");
System.out.println(sql1 + "\n" + sql1New);
String sql2 = "SELECT * FROM employee LIMIT 25";
String sql2New = sql2.replaceAll("(?i)(?:\\s+OFFSET \\d+)?\\s+LIMIT \\d+$", "");
System.out.println(sql2 + "\n" + sql2New);
```

This prints:

```
SELECT * FROM employee OFFSET 0 LIMIT 25
SELECT * FROM employee
SELECT * FROM employee LIMIT 25
SELECT * FROM employee
```